# How do I "link source" in an Android Gradle project?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm migrating to using Gradle in Eclipse. My project links a source directory that I reuse in several other projects.

Now I want to be able to use a Gradle task to build or install my app, but I don't know how to specify the other source directory.

Right now, my Eclipse workspace looks like this:

```
workspace/
    ParentGradleProject/
        core/
            src/
        android/
            src/
    mySharedLibrary_src/
```

I tried this but it's still not seeing the external src directory. See second line under `main`:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', '../../mySharedLibrary_src'] 
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Gradle as a build system for Android in Eclipse. The Android Gradle plugin is only supported in Android Studio/IntelliJ CE. This is because the plugin doesn't use normal Java sourceSets; it uses custom sourceSets that Eclipse's Gradle plugin isn't set up to understand. The failure you're seeing is from Eclipse not reading your sourceSet directive, falling back on its default, and only finding **src**.